# Failed to load remote configuration. OpenApi + Spring Boot + Docker + Proxy

Tags: spring-boot, docker, swagger, openapi

I have a spring project with two environments (A docker container for DEV and another container for PRE) due to customer requirements I have to access them through a proxy. When I try to access the documentation (OpenApi) it gives me the following error:

> Failed to load remote configuration.

From what I see in the console, the problem is with the configuration url:

[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKmlZ.png)

Missing proxy redirection,the correct url would be:

> http://[IP]/***proxy*dev**/v3/api-docs/swagger-config

But OpenApi tries this url:

> http://[IP]/v3/api-docs/swagger-config

I have tried to configure it through application.properties:

*application.properties:*

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.configUrl=http://[IP]/proxydev/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
```

But it shows me the documentation of Swagger Petstore:

[Swagger Petstore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqlja.png)

I have seen that you could create the swagger-config.json file and configure it from there:

*application.properties:*

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.configUrl=/swagger-config.json
```

*swagger-config.json:*

```
{
  "urls": [
    {
      "url": "http://[IP]/proxydev/v3/api-docs",
      "name": "name"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRKAs.png)

It works locally but when I compile and deploy it in the docker container it gives me again error may not find the file:

> Failed to load remote configuration.